# I want to create a new project from start

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a C# .cs project from "dotnet new console". I was wondering how to build this project into an executable .exe file.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at the [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) command. If you could specify your IDE, we could probably also give you an answer that isn't CLI based.

Comment: If you search for that in any search engine you should get plenty of results that show exactly how you can do that :)

Comment: See: [Hello World -- Your first program (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/hello-world-your-first-program) or [Tutorial: Create a simple C# console app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019).

Comment: My Ide oss visual studio code.

Comment: Don't use VS Code, use VS Community, it's a full featured IDE (not just an editor), that supports building, debugging and everything else you could want to do.  Oh, and it's FREE !

Comment: Allright! I think i installed the community one a while ago, just a side question here I hope you don't mind. Any perticular extentions I should have in general, and also for the C# language?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, then you can press Control+B (build) or F5 (build and run)